# nextcloud on AWS located on read-only disk

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nextcloud

I'm trying to install nextcloude server on Amazon virtual services AWS. I followed this wonderful and very useful [tutorial](https://www.virtualzero.net/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-creating-a-nextcloud-aws-ec2-instance-with-ubuntu-16.04-server) until step 30, when I had to allow my cloud server to be associated with a domain name.

When I tried to login using a new domain name, I got an error message

> Access through untrusted domain Please contact your administrator. If
>   you are an administrator, edit the "trusted_domains" setting in
>   config/config.php like the example in config.sample.php.
>
> Further information how to configure this can be found in the
>   documentation.

So I found the file, which is located in /snap/nextcloud/XXXX/htdocs/config, but whole /snap/nextcloud/XXXX file system in read-only

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop2      176M  176M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/XXXX
```

I think this means I have to buy storage space or somehow tell amazon, that I use this service as a cloud. Does anyone know how to make this system work?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed Nextcloud using Snap, which is a special type of package manager. A snap is a mini-filesystem which is mounted as read-only when used. Hence when mounted, this filesystem is 100% used.

The Nextcloud config file is available in the `/var/snap/nextcloud/current/nextcloud/config/` directory. This file is writable.

The snap will mount the `/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/data` into the snap as data directory for Nextcloud. The snap forwards port 80 (and 443) to its Apache webserver. All communication with Nextcloud will happen over these ports using the HTTP protocol, including file uploading and downloading.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have to admit that I never used snap and didn’t read documentation. My bad.! But if nexcloud runs in sabdboxed system, how is it possible to upload, download anything? It should be a trick. Could you please elaborate your answer a bit more?